# Delete iPhone MMS Messages Only

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm running out of space on my little 16GB iPhone 4S. I have noticed that a very large chunk of the space is taken up by the Messages app. I believe this is due to the tons of MMS messages I've sent and received over the years. I would like to easily delete all MMS messages (pictures/videos) without deleting any conversations and without having to manually find and delete each one. Is this possible?

Comment: When I faced the same problem recently, I thought about if, and how much I look back through the entire threads - meaning, "are they worth keeping around". I concluded that it was (a) too time intensive to just clear out media out of conversations, (b) I really don't look back through those conversations. I typically view the media, and then reply/move on. I still haven't missed that history. Just something to consider.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 7, in the conversation window, if you hold on a message balloon you get the context menu with two options: **Copy** and **More**.

When you tap **More**, you will get into the edit screen where you can select and delete individual messages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it would take me hours and hours to go through every conversation and every message in each to manually search for only MMS messages. Is there a way to find and delete all MMS messages automatically?

Answer (score -1):

go to settings, then messages, then scroll down to mms messaging and turn off.

Comment: This does not delete current messages, only prevents *sending* of MMS messages.